# SQL Pivot table : grouping rows and adding % in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Good morning everybody,
i'm starting to use pivot tables in SQL.

My starting table is very simple, just 2 variables : REGIONE and ESITO.

My first objective was to count ESITO for every REGIONE, so i did :

```
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        [ESITO],
        [REGIONE]
    FROM 
        [#temp]
) t
PIVOT(
    COUNT(ESITO) 
    FOR ESITO IN ([0],[9],[17],[19])
)
```

AS PivotTable

and it works fine, as i obtained :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvYdg.png

My next steps are :
-Adding a column to obtain the % of the counts
-Group the "REGIONE" variable to obtain 4 groups, each one has to show above the related cells.

So my result table should be smt like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAvIn.png

Could you help me to modify the query ?
Thanks in advance
Vittorio

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Note that most people here want sample data and expected result as formatted text, not images or links to images - make it easy to assist you!

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer. I'm sorry i didn't specified it before, anyway i'm using SQL Server Management Studio v18.12.1.

Comment: REGIONE   |  ESITO
PUGLIA       |  9
LOMBARDIA  | 19
LAZIO            | 17
VENETO         |  9
ABRUZZO      | 19
LOMBARDIA | 0
FRIULI-VENEZIA GIULIA | 17

Comment: Hey, not as comments. Edit your questions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to divide each value by the total across the row

```sql
SELECT
  REGIONE,
  [0],
  Pct0  = [0]  * 1.0 / ([0] + [9] + [17] + [19]),
  [9],
  Pct9  = [9]  * 1.0 / ([0] + [9] + [17] + [19]),
  [17],
  Pct17 = [17] * 1.0 / ([0] + [9] + [17] + [19]),
  [19],
  Pct19 = [19] * 1.0 / ([0] + [9] + [17] + [19])
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ESITO,
        REGIONE
    FROM 
        #temp
) t
PIVOT(
    COUNT(ESITO) 
    FOR ESITO IN ([0],[9],[17],[19])
) pvt;
```

In future a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) would help immensely.

Comment: Thanks Charlieface, it's just the result i needed :)